# More opportunities to help MMSE with your artistic skills!

Tags: discussion, sponsorship-and-advertising, site-promotion, design

First, I'd really like to thank Anoop Nair and Pranoy Ray for their help with: [Logo needed for community ads!](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/122/5) and [Let's work on our logo! (Improving on Anoop Nair's design)](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/5).

Everyone is welcome to make adjustments to these logos by directly editing the [open Google Drawing file](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1pHmns7C6UWacWsofiJsrI50923R0q6mMDVKt12JcMyY/edit?usp=sharing) or making edits to the images being used in it, [which are located in the GitHub folder](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/Logo).

Now in addition to the more square-like format for community ads, [we are also allowed to advertise MMSE with banner ads](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8800/14527). We therefore need volunteers to help make some logos/ads in the banner-type format, so that we can advertise MMSE in this way on other sites such as Physics.SE and Chemistry.SE. I recommend following the same collaboration format as for the above cases (make a freely editable Google Drawing file, and place all files/images on which it depends in the GitHub folder for the logos).